# High res community advert

Tags: feature-request, images, open-source-advertising

The current requirements for the community adverts are:

> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

The key one there that I want to bring up is the 220 x 250 pixels.  Many of us have high res screens now - either on our laptops or tablets.  When one sees (most specifically) text at this size in the community adverts, it looks blurry.

Please change the guidelines to specify either 220 x 250 or 440 x 500 (and encourage high resolution when it fits within the 150 KB file size).

For those who have a high res display and wish to see the blurriness compared:

440x500:
[image]

vs:

220x250:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As of 2016, this was available.