# What size should community ads actually be?

Tags: support, open-source-advertising, community-promotion-ads

The guidelines in the automated posts say "...must be 220 x 250 pixels", with a maximum file size of 150kB. But apparently enterprising folks have discovered that 440x500 works, for example, [this ad on gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10175/2903).

Is that size definitely supported? Is it the best size for making things look good on higher resolution screens? If so, could the guidelines be updated?

Comment: Maybe it'll just be resized when used?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, I assume that happens - it's just that the guidelines explicitly say "The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels" not really leaving much room for "...or something else in that aspect ratio."

Comment: Hmm... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246442/high-res-community-advert

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/160917

Answer (score 2):

The guidelines in the meta posts that collect the ads have been updated, and now include:

> - The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.

([Example](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4377/28))

Using the larger size is better for those using high-DPI displays.  Do test it at 50% reduction to make sure it looks ok that way too, as that's how some people will be seeing it.  But if your ad looks good at the larger size and when resized, use the larger size when submitting the ad.